# Shrinking tube or bending a cone

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I would like to make curved cone (I'm making 3D model of [this dialog bubbles](http://comps.canstockphoto.com/can-stock-photo_csp2186532.jpg) and I want to use curved cones to make line between the bubble and speaker.

During my research I found, that I can either make cone and then curve it according to a bezier curve, or I can make path, use circle as its bevel object and then shrink it using taper object [as described in this video](https://youtu.be/tTvD9_fDQOQ?t=264).

Both approaches have problems. With the first approach it is extremely hard to bend the cone the way I want and I can't get proper results. The other approach is works well, when the path is straight. If the path is curved, then after the taper object the tube disappears.

What would be the good way to do that? I would very much prefer the path and bevel objects approach, because it does almost exactly what I need.

Comment: use another curve circle as a taper object and it should be enough, for precise control use a straight  curve and move the points on the Y axis

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't seem to work (the circle as taper object). It is probably because I'm beginner and I don't know precisely what to do. If you are in the mood, feel free to write that again as a more detailed answer :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT**

To create a bent conical object. Start with a **Curve** and a Bezier Circle (Add Curve->Circle) as **Bevel** object:

[image]

Then change the **Radius** for the control points of the curve:

[image]

**Other Ideas:**

Do the whole object as a curve:

[image]

then fill it as a 2D

[image]

Then add a bevel:

[image]

If you add a Curve->Circle as a bevel Object you can so something like this:

[image]